# Blocking Database access from test server to production database and vice versa

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have setup two sites and two databases on Azure. A test site and a production site.
We had an issue recently where a developer made a mistake and deployed code to our production website with a connections string pointed to our test SQL server. 
I am wondering if it is possible to limit access to the production SQL Server so that it only accepts connections from the production web site. And limit the test SQL Server so that it only accepts connections from the test web site.
I would ultimately like to configure it so that if this happens again, the site just wouldn't work because it would not authenticate correctly.
I am in the process of creating an additional set of configuration files so that we have a set that points to test related settings, and one for production, but how do you prevent somebody from screwing up and deploying the wrong connection string to the wrong environment? All database activity on the site is going through a WEB API.

Comment: I don't know about Azure, but in AWS you can place servers in different security groups and setup firewall rules that prevent access across groups.  Is there anything similar in Azure?

Comment: There are [firewall rules for Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx).  Here is a [good article on setting them up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553530.aspx)